# I want my jQuery animation to work only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want this to work only once. For now, my scroll top always work and so it's impossible to scroll down my page.

```
$(function() {
    $(".showhover").hover(
    function() {
        $('div.mouseover').show(),
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('div.mouseover').innerHeight() });
    });
});
```

Comment: `.one()` is your friend here.

Comment: From now on, yes he is !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `one()`, but `hover()` is a custom function in jQuery packaging mouseenter and mouseleave together, and doing `one('hover')` would attach to the `hover` event, which is not recommended.

When using mouseenter / mouseleave you have to revert the functionality yourself :

```
$(function() {
    $(".showhover").one({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $('div.mouseover').show(),
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('div.mouseover').innerHeight() });
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('div.mouseover').hide(),
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `one('mouseenter mouseleave'`, hover is a pseudo event for the combination of mouseenter and mouseleave.

```
$(".showhover").one('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        $('div.mouseover').toggle();
        if(e.type === 'mouseenter')
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('div.mouseover').innerHeight() });
});
```